# How to alias a variable to a command containing a variable which contains a left parenthesis

Tags: linux, alias, parentheses

To list individual paths in my $PATH variable on separate lines for readability, I've had this command in my .bashrc (on Cygwin) for a long time:

```
alias path="echo $PATH | perl -pe 's/:/\n/g'"
```

It used to always work, but now, it fails when I execute path alias on the command line:

```
$ path
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I believe this is because my path contains `Program Files (x86)`. It's the parenthesis that is causing the problem, as when I hard code a string containing a path that doesn't contain parenthesis, it works, but when I hard code a string that does contain parenthesis, it does not work.

This works:

```
$ alias path="echo /usr/local/bin:Program Files:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32 | perl -pe 's/:/\n/g'"
$ path
/usr/local/bin
Program Files
/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32
```

But this doesn't:

```
$ alias path="echo /usr/local/bin:Program Files (x86):/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32 | perl -pe 's/:/\n/g'"
$ path
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Thanks.

Comment: Put the alias in single quotes, or escape the `$`. It's expanding the variable when you define the alias, not when you execute it.

Comment: Or use a function instead of alias.